# Convert web service configuration to code

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf, .net-3.5

I have a client for SOAP service in a console application, I need to move the service client to sharepoint 2010. I do not want to do config files deployment and other sharepoint-related stuff, so I decided to hardcode binding information, the only configurable option is URL. But I encountred some troubles doing this. I have a config:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="SI_PMProjectMaintain_SOUTBinding">
      <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
        messageVersion="Soap11" writeEncoding="utf-8">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="10000000" maxStringContentLength="10000000"
          maxArrayLength="67108864" maxBytesPerRead="65536" maxNameTableCharCount="100000" />
      </textMessageEncoding>
      <httpTransport authenticationScheme="Basic" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
        hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" keepAliveEnabled="false"
        proxyAuthenticationScheme="Basic" realm="XISOAPApps" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://url/XISOAPAdapter/MessageServlet?senderParty=&amp;senderService=Param1&amp;receiverParty=&amp;receiverService=&amp;interface=interface&amp;interfaceNamespace=url"
    binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="SI_PMProjectMaintain_SOUTBinding"
    contract="PmProjectMaintain.SI_PMProjectMaintain_SOUT" name="HTTP_Port" />
</client>
```

Also, I have a code:

```
    var service = new ServiceClient();
    service.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
    service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "user";
    service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";

    var resp = service.Operation();
    Console.WriteLine(resp.Response);
```

It works as expected. Now I want to get rid of xml config and completly move it to code:

```
public class CustomHttpTransportBinding : CustomBinding
{
    public CustomHttpTransportBinding()
    {
    }

    public override BindingElementCollection CreateBindingElements()
    {
        var result = new BindingElementCollection();
        result.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement
        {
            MaxReadPoolSize = 64,
            MaxWritePoolSize = 16,
            MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap11,
            WriteEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,

            //ReaderQuotas = new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
            //{
            //    MaxDepth = 10000000,
            //    MaxStringContentLength = 10000000,
            //    MaxArrayLength = 67108864,
            //    MaxBytesPerRead = 65536,
            //    MaxNameTableCharCount = 100000
            //}
        });

        result.Add(new HttpTransportBindingElement
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic,
            BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
            HostNameComparisonMode = System.ServiceModel.HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard,
            KeepAliveEnabled = false,
            ProxyAuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic,
            Realm = "XISOAPApps",
            UseDefaultWebProxy = true
        });

        return result;
    }
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
    var service = new ServiceClient(new CustomHttpTransportBinding(), new EndpointAddress(url));
    service.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
    service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "user";
    service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";

    var resp = service.Operation();
    Console.WriteLine(resp.Response);
```

It reaches the server, but throws exception ("Server Error"), so I belive something wrong with my configuration. I can not specify the reader quotas also. I've tried loading [configuration from string](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimmytr/archive/2011/02/15/snippet-construct-wcf-binding-from-string-xml.aspx), but it is not worked for me, same error.
Confi
It seems that I can not convert custom bindings from XML to code in .net 3.5. Can somebody take a look on my code and confirm? Are there other ways to have a service client with custom binding in code?

Comment: What happens when you try to specify the reader quotas?  Also, have you checked the event viewer to see if there is any information about the error there?

Comment: I've tried to specify reader quotas on .net 4.5, same error. Do you mean event viewer on a server? Unfortunately it is SAP service and I do not have access to that environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not found a way to move configuration from app.config to code for a custom binding, it works greate for basicHttpBinding, but does not work for customBinding.

I've ended up with loading the configuration dynamicaly from file using custom chanell factory.

```
public class CustomChannelFactory<T> : ChannelFactory<T>
{
    private readonly string _configurationPath;

    public CustomChannelFactory(string configurationPath) : base(typeof(T))
    {
        _configurationPath = configurationPath;
        base.InitializeEndpoint((string)null, null);
    }

    protected override ServiceEndpoint CreateDescription()
    {
        ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint = base.CreateDescription();

        ExeConfigurationFileMap executionFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
        executionFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = _configurationPath;

        System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(executionFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        ServiceModelSectionGroup serviceModeGroup = ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(config);

        ChannelEndpointElement selectedEndpoint = null;
        foreach (ChannelEndpointElement endpoint in serviceModeGroup.Client.Endpoints)
        {
            if (endpoint.Contract == serviceEndpoint.Contract.ConfigurationName)
            {
                selectedEndpoint = endpoint;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (selectedEndpoint != null)
        {
            if (serviceEndpoint.Binding == null)
            {
                serviceEndpoint.Binding = CreateBinding(selectedEndpoint.Binding, serviceModeGroup);
            }

            if (serviceEndpoint.Address == null)
            {
                serviceEndpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(selectedEndpoint.Address, GetIdentity(selectedEndpoint.Identity), selectedEndpoint.Headers.Headers);
            }

            if (serviceEndpoint.Behaviors.Count == 0 && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedEndpoint.BehaviorConfiguration))
            {
                AddBehaviors(selectedEndpoint.BehaviorConfiguration, serviceEndpoint, serviceModeGroup);
            }

            serviceEndpoint.Name = selectedEndpoint.Contract;
        }

        return serviceEndpoint;
    }

    private Binding CreateBinding(string bindingName, ServiceModelSectionGroup group)
    {
        BindingCollectionElement bindingElementCollection = group.Bindings[bindingName];
        if (bindingElementCollection.ConfiguredBindings.Count > 0)
        {
            IBindingConfigurationElement be = bindingElementCollection.ConfiguredBindings[0];

            Binding binding = GetBinding(be);
            if (be != null)
            {
                be.ApplyConfiguration(binding);
            }

            return binding;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void AddBehaviors(string behaviorConfiguration, ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, ServiceModelSectionGroup group)
    {
        EndpointBehaviorElement behaviorElement = group.Behaviors.EndpointBehaviors[behaviorConfiguration];
        for (int i = 0; i < behaviorElement.Count; i++)
        {
            BehaviorExtensionElement behaviorExtension = behaviorElement[i];
            object extension = behaviorExtension.GetType().InvokeMember("CreateBehavior",
            BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
            null, behaviorExtension, null);
            if (extension != null)
            {
                serviceEndpoint.Behaviors.Add((IEndpointBehavior)extension);
            }
        }
    }

    private EndpointIdentity GetIdentity(IdentityElement element)
    {
        EndpointIdentity identity = null;
        PropertyInformationCollection properties = element.ElementInformation.Properties;
        if (properties["userPrincipalName"].ValueOrigin != PropertyValueOrigin.Default)
        {
            return EndpointIdentity.CreateUpnIdentity(element.UserPrincipalName.Value);
        }
        if (properties["servicePrincipalName"].ValueOrigin != PropertyValueOrigin.Default)
        {
            return EndpointIdentity.CreateSpnIdentity(element.ServicePrincipalName.Value);
        }
        if (properties["dns"].ValueOrigin != PropertyValueOrigin.Default)
        {
            return EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity(element.Dns.Value);
        }
        if (properties["rsa"].ValueOrigin != PropertyValueOrigin.Default)
        {
            return EndpointIdentity.CreateRsaIdentity(element.Rsa.Value);
        }
        if (properties["certificate"].ValueOrigin != PropertyValueOrigin.Default)
        {
            X509Certificate2Collection supportingCertificates = new X509Certificate2Collection();
            supportingCertificates.Import(Convert.FromBase64String(element.Certificate.EncodedValue));
            if (supportingCertificates.Count == 0)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("UnableToLoadCertificateIdentity");
            }
            X509Certificate2 primaryCertificate = supportingCertificates[0];
            supportingCertificates.RemoveAt(0);
            return EndpointIdentity.CreateX509CertificateIdentity(primaryCertificate, supportingCertificates);
        }

        return identity;
    }

    private Binding GetBinding(IBindingConfigurationElement configurationElement)
    {
        if (configurationElement is CustomBindingElement)
            return new CustomBinding();
        else if (configurationElement is BasicHttpBindingElement)
            return new BasicHttpBinding();
        else if (configurationElement is NetMsmqBindingElement)
            return new NetMsmqBinding();
        else if (configurationElement is NetNamedPipeBindingElement)
            return new NetNamedPipeBinding();
        else if (configurationElement is NetPeerTcpBindingElement)
            return new NetPeerTcpBinding();
        else if (configurationElement is NetTcpBindingElement)
            return new NetTcpBinding();
        else if (configurationElement is WSDualHttpBindingElement)
            return new WSDualHttpBinding();
        else if (configurationElement is WSHttpBindingElement)
            return new WSHttpBinding();
        else if (configurationElement is WSFederationHttpBindingElement)
            return new WSFederationHttpBinding();

        return null;
    }
}
```

Usefull links:

- [Loading WCF configuration from different files (source code is not availiable)](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/loading-the-wcf-configuration-from-different-files-on-the-client-side)
- [Thread with source code of CustomChannelFactory](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f33e620a-e332-4fd4-ae21-88c750437355/config-hosting-multiple-wcf-services-in-one-nt-service?forum=wcf)
- [.NET 4.0 ChanellFactory (wish it was in .net 3.5)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2010/09/02/loading-wcf-client-configuration-from-different-files-with-configurationchannelfactory.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Found an issue with the code referenced in boades reply, in that if you have mixed transport bindings (`https`/`http`) under `basicHttpbinding` you are likely to get an exception similar/reverse of this:

> The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'. Parameter name: via

I'd also expect you will also have unexpected authorization occurring, again as the code will use the first `bindingConfiguration` listed in the `web.config` rather than by name.

The offending line which doesn't take the binding by name, but rather just takes the 1st one(!)

IBindingConfigurationElement be = bindingElementCollection.ConfiguredBindings[0];

This could be corrected by updating `CreateBinding` method and the call in `CreateDescription` like so:

```
protected override ServiceEndpoint CreateDescription()
{
    ServiceEndpoint description = base.CreateDescription();
    if (CustomisedChannelFactory<TChannel>.ConfigurationPath == null || !System.IO.File.Exists(CustomisedChannelFactory<TChannel>.ConfigurationPath))
        return base.CreateDescription();
    ServiceModelSectionGroup sectionGroup = ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(new ExeConfigurationFileMap()
    {
        ExeConfigFilename = CustomisedChannelFactory<TChannel>.ConfigurationPath
    }, ConfigurationUserLevel.None));
    ChannelEndpointElement channelEndpointElement1 = (ChannelEndpointElement)null;
    foreach (ChannelEndpointElement channelEndpointElement2 in (ConfigurationElementCollection)sectionGroup.Client.Endpoints)
    {
        if (channelEndpointElement2.Contract == description.Contract.ConfigurationName)
        {
            channelEndpointElement1 = channelEndpointElement2;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (channelEndpointElement1 != null)
    {
        if (description.Binding == null)
            description.Binding = this.CreateBinding(channelEndpointElement1.Binding, channelEndpointElement1.BindingConfiguration, sectionGroup);
        if (description.Address == (EndpointAddress)null)
            description.Address = new EndpointAddress(channelEndpointElement1.Address, this.GetIdentity(channelEndpointElement1.Identity), channelEndpointElement1.Headers.Headers);
        if (description.Behaviors.Count == 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(channelEndpointElement1.BehaviorConfiguration))
            this.AddBehaviors(channelEndpointElement1.BehaviorConfiguration, description, sectionGroup);
        description.Name = channelEndpointElement1.Contract;
    }
    return description;
}

private Binding CreateBinding(string bindingName, string bindingConfigurationName, ServiceModelSectionGroup group)
{
    BindingCollectionElement collectionElement = group.Bindings[bindingName];
    if (collectionElement.ConfiguredBindings.Count <= 0)
        return (Binding)null;

    IBindingConfigurationElement configurationElement = null;
    foreach (IBindingConfigurationElement bce in collectionElement.ConfiguredBindings)
    {
        if (bce.Name.Equals(bindingConfigurationName))
        {
            configurationElement = bce;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (configurationElement == null) throw new Exception("BindingConfiguration " + bindingConfigurationName + " not found under binding " + bindingName);

    Binding binding = this.GetBinding(configurationElement);
    if (configurationElement != null)
        configurationElement.ApplyConfiguration(binding);
    return binding;
}
```