# Create WCF client via external configs

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config

I have two different external config files and one main web.config.

App.config

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ServiceEndpointName" value="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Client.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://someURL/Service1.svc/soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="TestWCF.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Now, I want to create a client of Service1. So I have used following code.

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();

configMap.ExeConfigFilename = @"G:\App.config";
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

var ServiceEndpointName = config.AppSettings.Settings["ServiceEndpointName"].Value;

configMap.ExeConfigFilename = @"G:\Client.config";
config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var servicesFactory = new ConfigurationChannelFactory<TestWCF.IService1>(ServiceEndpointName, config, null);
var client = servicesFactory.CreateChannel();
```

But, it's throw an error like

Could not find endpoint element with name 'BasicHttpBinding_IService1' and contract 'TestWCF.IService1' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.

How can I resolve this issue?
I have removed client section and bindings section from my main web.config. I do not want to use client section from my weg.config.

Comment: Please check for a possible solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26102499/convert-web-service-configuration-to-code?noredirect=1#comment40911752_26102499). I tried this and it created my WCF service client successfully.

Comment: @OguzOzgul - Thanks!